# StringArray in Java

Tags: java

```
class A {
    public static void main(String args []){
        int val = (int) ((Math.random) * 5);
        String res = new String [ ]{"Rahul","Javed","Kunal","Ram"}[val];
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

When val had value 1, "Javed" was printed - but how and what is [val] at the end of the "String res =" expression.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: `[val]` means that you access the element at position `val` in the array.

Comment: Hint: Arrays start with index 0 in Java..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`someArray[index]` is the way to access to an element of an array in an especific index. In this case you are creating an array:

```
new String[] { "Rahul", "Javed", "Kunal", "Ram" }
```

then accessing to an element by:

```
new String[] { "Rahul", "Javed", "Kunal", "Ram" }[val]
```

This is similar to

```
someArray[val]
```

where `val` is the index. Remember that indexes in Java (and in most programming languages) start with 0.

Comment: @Aamir please accept the answer if you feel it is correct!